# автоматическое тестирование проектов на gitlab

Tags: java, github, gitlab, test-automation

начинающий юзер гитлаба, просьба не пинать ногами, меня интересует тестирование java-проектов на автомате, то есть написал тесты закинул в проект на гитлабе и они работают на автомате

с чего необходимо начать, как это делается, куда смотреть, где копать? в общем буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Answer (score 2):

Есть три независимых друг от друга задачи:

1. Написать сами тесты и реализовать возможность их запуска из командной строки. Можно просто команду, можно в `.sh` обернуть. Главное: тесты должны действительно фейлиться при запуске, то есть:

   - Если тесты успешны, запускатор тестов возвращает `0`.
   - Если тесты неуспешны, запускатор возвращает что угодно другое.
2. Установить и настроить [GitLab CI Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) на машине с нужной вам ОС. Если вы пользуетесь gitlab.com, можете воспользоваться раннерами, предоставленными GitLab.

   - Потом настроить ваш репозиторий на этот раннер.
3. Добавить в корневую папку проекта файл `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Это файл в разметке Yaml, он описывает конвейер (pipeline) сборки проекта. Если GitLab видит этот файл в коммите, он пытается запустить сборку.

Содержимое `.gitlab-ci.yml` примерно такое

```
# если используем Docker-runner
# то, например, такой образ Java можно использовать
image: openjdk:7

# у нас будет только один этап сборки — тест
stages:
  - test

# и в нём только одна задача
test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
  # предположим, что тесты мы запускаем с помощью Maven
    - mvn test
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно прочитать документацию по настройке файла .gitlab-ci.yml

Он запускает ранеры для выполнения задач при комите или мерже в зависимости он его настроек.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/

Вам также нужно будет настроить сам ранер (в начале можно на той-же машине что и gitlab )
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/